# Nested loop infinitely looping after random interval?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

I am programming a connect 4 game using Java for an assignment. However, whenever player 2 makes a move about 5 moves in, the player 2 loop will infinitely loop. There is some sort of logic error that I cannot find, and it is frustrating. What is the logic error, and what is a good way to avoid future mistakes of the same vain?

I have tried changing the variables for the do > while loop where player 1 and player two attempt their moves. However that has no affect on it.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Lab6Shell {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // variables
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        char[][] board = new char[7][8];
        boolean finished = false;
        boolean gameOver = false;
        int width = 7;
        int height = 8;
        char currentPlayer = 'X';
        int numMoves = 0;
        int bottom_row = width - 1;

        // loop until user wants to stop
        for (int row = 0; row < board.length; row++) {
            java.util.Arrays.fill(board[row], 0, board[row].length, '*');
        }
        do {

            // display the board

            DisplayBoard(board);

            // loop until this game is over
            do {
                // get the next move for the current player
                int columnChosen = 0;
                do {

                    if (currentPlayer == 'X') {

                        int counter = 1;

                        System.out.println("Player 1 turn");

                        System.out.println("Enter the column you want to place your piece.");
                        columnChosen = input.nextInt();
                        input.nextLine();

                        while (true) {
                            if (columnChosen > width) {
                                System.out.println("That's not a valid column");
                                break;
                            }

                            if ((board[bottom_row][columnChosen] == '*')) {
                                board[bottom_row][columnChosen] = 'X';
                                break;
                            } else if ((board[bottom_row][columnChosen] == 'X')
                                    || (board[bottom_row][columnChosen] == 'O')) {
                                if (board[bottom_row - counter][columnChosen] == '*') { // puts X if blank
                                    board[bottom_row - counter][columnChosen] = 'X';
                                    break;
                                }

                                counter += 1;
                                if (counter == width) {
                                    System.out.println("That column is full");
                                    break;
                                }
                            }

                        }
                    }

                    if (currentPlayer == 'O') {

                        int counter = 1;

                        System.out.println("Player 2's turn");

                        System.out.println("Enter the column you want to place your piece.");
                        columnChosen = input.nextInt();
                        input.nextLine();

                        while (true) {
                            if (columnChosen > width) {
                                System.out.println("That's not a valid column");
                                break;
                            }

                            if ((board[bottom_row][columnChosen] == '*')) {
                                board[bottom_row][columnChosen] = 'O';
                                break;
                            } else if ((board[bottom_row][columnChosen] == 'X')
                                    || (board[bottom_row][columnChosen] == 'O')) {
                                if (board[bottom_row - counter][columnChosen] == '*') { // puts O
                                    board[bottom_row - counter][columnChosen] = 'O';
                                    break;
                                }

                                counter += 1;
                                if (counter == width) {
                                    System.out.println("That column is full");
                                    break;
                                }
                            }

                        }
                    }

                } while (columnChosen < 0 || columnChosen > 8 || board[1][columnChosen] != '*');

                // place piece

                // increment number of moves
                numMoves++;
                // display the board
                DisplayBoard(board);

                // check for win
                if (checkWin(board)) {
                    // if winner, display congratulations and set gameOver true
                    System.out.println("Congratulations! You won!");
                    gameOver = true;
                } else if (numMoves == 42) {
                    // if tie, display result and set gameOver true
                    DisplayBoard(board);
                    System.out.println("Tie Game! Game over");
                    gameOver = true;
                } else if (checkWin(board) == false) {
                    if (currentPlayer == ('X')) {
                        currentPlayer = ('O');
                    } else {
                        currentPlayer = ('X');
                    }
                }

            } while (!gameOver);

            // ask if user wants to play again, set finished accordingly
            System.out.println("Would you like to play again?");
            input.nextLine();
            String decision = input.nextLine();

            if (decision.toLowerCase().equals("yes")) {
                finished = false;
            }

            else if (decision.toLowerCase().equals("no")) {
                finished = true;
            }

        } while (finished == false);
    }

    // this method displays the board passed in
    public static void DisplayBoard(char[][] board) {
        for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
            System.out.print("|");
            for (int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(" " + board[i][j] + "|");

            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }

    public static boolean checkWin(char[][] board) {
        final int HEIGHT = board.length;
        final int WIDTH = board[0].length;
        final int EMPTY_SLOT = '*';
        for (int r = 0; r < HEIGHT; r++) { // iterate rows, bottom to top
            for (int c = 0; c < WIDTH; c++) { // iterate columns, left to right
                char player = board[r][c];
                if (player == EMPTY_SLOT)
                    continue; // don't check empty slots

                if (c + 3 < WIDTH && player == board[r][c + 1] && // look right
                        player == board[r][c + 2] && player == board[r][c + 3])
                    return true;
                if (r + 3 < HEIGHT) {
                    if (player == board[r + 1][c] && // look up
                            player == board[r + 2][c] && player == board[r + 3][c])
                        return true;
                    if (c + 3 < WIDTH && player == board[r + 1][c + 1] && // look up & right
                            player == board[r + 2][c + 2] && player == board[r + 3][c + 3])
                        return true;
                    if (c - 3 >= 0 && player == board[r + 1][c - 1] && // look up & left
                            player == board[r + 2][c - 2] && player == board[r + 3][c - 3])
                        return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false; // no winner found
    }

}
```

The expected result is that each player will play a piece until four of the same piece are in a row. Then the first to reach four in a row is declared the winner, and the game ends. However, once the game gets in about 5 loops, the player 2 loop infinitely loops until a column is full, and does not print out the board.

Comment: how have you been taught to debug your code?

Comment: I do not know how to use the debugger, no. I use Eclipse

Comment: Are you sure that your `while (true)` loops will always terminate?

Comment: The only thing I can think of that may be an issue is that somehow the counter may be the issue. otherwise I do not see why the loop would not terminate

Comment: I recommend you break your code up into several smaller functions. Doing that may help you better understand the flow, and in the event that the problem persists, you may have an easier time locating the issue and which loop is failing to terminate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your infinite loop is caused by checking the condition `board[1][columnChosen] != '*'` in your `do ... while` loop.  The program will continue to ask the current user for a new move as long as the second to top row of the selected column is occupied.

Replace:

```
do 
{
...
} while (columnChosen < 0 || columnChosen > 8 || board[1][columnChosen] != '*');
```

With:

```
do
{
...
} while (columnChosen < 0 || columnChosen > 8)
```

This should get you to a point where you can tackle the remaining issues.

Comment: Thank you so much, this helped immensely. I know everyone hates people asking for homework help on here so I appreciate it